# Open an external port into Istio - problem only on docker-for-mac

Tags: kubernetes, gateway, istio, docker-for-mac

Update: This problem is only on docker-for-mac

I have been chasing this for some time now - how do you open an external port into Istio.

Note all this works on `port 80`, why not on `port 8080`?

Using helm, I have changed value in `values.yaml` gateways:

```
- port: 80
  targetPort: 80
  name: http2
  # nodePort: 31380
- port: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  name: http2-testport
  # nodePort: 31480
```

I have created a Istion Gateway:

```
# Istio - Gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: helloworld-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-80
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "my-service.default.svc.cluster.local"

  - port:
      number: 8080
      name: http-8080
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "my-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

Port 8080 is open: `kubectl get svc -n istio-system`

```
istio-ingressgateway       LoadBalancer   10.106.146.89    localhost     80:31342/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31735/TCP,8060:32568/TCP,8080:32164/TCP,853:30443/TCP,15030:
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `VirtualService` to specify where (to which microservice) the ingress traffic must be directed, see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#configuring-ingress-using-an-istio-gateway.

Also try to send the Host header with your request, e.g. with `curl` -H Host:my-service.default.svc.cluster.local.

See https://github.com/istio/istio.github.io/pull/2181.

Comment: Thanks, I have a VirtualService(and same service for both) and it works for port 80?

Comment: You may want to provide the `VirtualService` definition in the body of the question, and also some diagnostic steps - the output of `kubectl get svc -n istio-system`, how you access the cluster, what is the error you get, etc.

Comment: Have you exposed a port into Istio?

Comment: Thanks added: kubectl get svc -n istio-system

Comment: I updated the answer - Also try to send the Host header with your request, e.g. with curl -H Host:my-service.default.svc.cluster.local.

Comment: Thanks, with curl I get: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: Are you using minikube?

Comment: I use Google Kubernetes Engine & Docker-For-Desktop for mac. I get the same nothing on both.

Comment: Sorry, no it works on Google Kubernetes Engine :-| So the problem must be with Docker-For-Desktop. Hmm

Comment: so how can you access GKE by the `localhost` address? How do you access GKE with port 80? Can you try these instructions for GKE? https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports-when-using-a-node-port, including the part for GKE.

Comment: GKE, well then it is not localhost :-) I use the service ip address Istio Gateway north/south ingress exposes. Just switching between contexts when testing. But, I have been knocking on this for some time now, and I did one thing - this time. If it is some yaml I have cleaned up from my trials or it is a fix in 1.0.1 I dont know - but it works on GKE.

Comment: So now you can access the port 8080 of the Istio ingress gateway, can't you?

Comment: That is correct but only on GKE. Therefore it is probably not Istio but docker-for-mac on localhost loadbalancer.